# Jbutton changing value in +1 increments using netbeans

Tags: java, class, methods, jbutton

im having trouble getting the jbuttton to plus 1 number it keeps returning just one in the printout, i want to create a method that is a base method for other jbuttons which will all max out at 10 and print out the value onto a label using a settext but i cant figure out why the amount stays at 1 every click

```
package calculator;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Dominic
 */
public class calc extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  int clicked; 

  public int method() {
   if (clicked < 10)
       clicked++;
   else {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "maxed");
   }
   System.out.println(clicked);
   return clicked ;}



    public calc() {
        initComponents();
    }                                  

    private void jbtn12ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
       calc newcalc = new calc();
       newcalc.method();
    }
```

Comment: Could you format your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `jbtn12ActionPerformed`, you create a new calc, and increase and print the value of that new calc.

There are different approaches that might help you:

#### Option 1

Make the variable *clicked* of type **static**. Just changing this will solve your problem, but I don't believe it's the right way to do so.

#### Option 2

Make the variable *clicked* of type **static**. **AND** make the method *method* static, and call it instead of what you are doing (change the actionPerformed method to:

```
calc.method();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make clicked public static. 
every time you are making a new instance of calc and that initializes 'clicked' with zero every time;